# Disable History Sync in Chrome from extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-history

Is it possible to disable History Sync in Chrome from my extension?

I'm making an extension which can turn off history recording, but it only works when History Sync is disabled in Chrome settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no such capability (to change Sync settings) exists in the [API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index).

Answer (score 0):

I work little with chrome extension but I guess this might help.
First add this code to extension manifest
`{
        "name": "My extension",
        ...
        "permissions": [
        "browsingdata"
        "history"
        ],
        ...
      }`
Then you might use their built-in methods to implement your logic.